# How to access database using promise with fetch function?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express, promise, fetch

I'm trying to access the mongo db from the front end using promise with fetch() function but it's not working.

```
var Promise = () => (
  new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    //do something, fetch something....
    //you guessed it, mongo queries go here.
    db.collection('users').find()
    console.log('users');
     .then(function(result){
    var somethingWentWrong = (dataReturned == null);
    (somethingWentWrong)
      ? reject('something messed up')
      : resolve(result);
  })
)

<tr>
<div class="first">
<td class="data">{{ this.firstname}}</td>
</div>
<div class="last">
<td class="data">{{ this.lastname}}</td>
</div>
<div class="email">
<td class="data">{{ this.email }}</td>
</div>
</tr>
```

Comment: Where does here `fetch()` used??. Also its server side coding, but your post says its frontend. Any error??

Comment: And you really shouldn't be shadowing the global `Promise` object.

Comment: I added the front end code just now. Thank you.

Comment: you have to make a **RESTAPI** for getUsers and it work be like

api/users/

which is based on **node.js**

then you have to write a controller where you get all users in collection.


`getUsers(){
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
db.collection("user").findOne({}, (err, result) => {
    if (err) throw err;
    resolve(result);
  }).catch(error =>{
    reject(error)
});

})
}`

Answer (score 0):

> let dataReturned = db.collection('users').find({}, {}).asArray();

```
new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    //do something, fetch something....
    //you guessed it, mongo queries go here.

    let dataReturned = db.collection('users').find({}, {}).asArray();

    console.log('users');
    var somethingWentWrong = (dataReturned == null);
    (somethingWentWrong)
      ? reject('something messed up')
      : resolve(dataReturned);
})
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. It's still not returning any data :(

Comment: are u sure that connection to the DB has been made?
getting any error ?
need more information

Comment: Yes I have connected the database and it is working correctly. There are no errors. and I don't understand how to use the fetch function.